# Firebase database security rules allow authenticated user to read and write from their own contents

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here's my database structure:

```
 Clients:
     employee1emailaddress
     employee2emailaddress
 Employees:
     employee1emailaddress
     employee2emailaddress
 allClients:
     client1phonenumber
     client2phonenumber
```

I want to make a security rule to limit the authenticated user to **read** and **write** from nodes associated to their **email address**

For example:
the employee who has the email address of `employee1emailaddress` can **only read from and write to the nodes that has their email addresses as the key**

How to make that possible ? and thanks in advance..

Comment: What have you tried, and why doesn't it work as you expect?

Comment: I searched for a way to do this, all the security rules i found are depending on $uid, but as you can see I'm using email address as the key, not the ID

Comment: After a few days, I found a way. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57635184/firebase-realtime-database-private-shared-data-with-e-mail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend not associating data with a user's email address. You should use their UID instead:

```
{
  "rules": {
     "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

This will only allow users to read and write from a directory in your database where the key is their UID.

Comment: This would work for all the nodes `(Clients & Employees & allClients)` 
Right ?

And is there a way to apply this rule for user's email instead ?

Comment: I do believe that there is a way to do this, but using UIDs is better because you won't have to move data if a user changes their email address. While this will work for multiple nodes, any user will be able to edit their own directory on any node. I would recommend tagging the user and only letting them use the proper node, or not dividing the database into three nodes, and instead storing all users together.

Comment: @Terren with latest firebase 2023, it errs `Error saving rules – Line 3: Unknown variable '$uid'.; Line 4: Unknown variable '$uid'.`

Comment: if nested inside `$uid:`, even `".read": true,` denies reading

Comment: https://gist.github.com/codediodeio/6dbce1305b9556c2136492522e2100f6