# Firebase Realtime Database Private Shared Data With E-Mail?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want to share secure data between users.

```
"shared_requests" : {
    "shared_uid" : {
      "deviceSeriNo" : "device1serino",
      "user1" : {
        "email" : "john@john.com",
        "userName" : "John"
      },
      "user2" : {
        "email" : "micheal@micheal.com",
        "userName" : "Micheal"
      }
    }
  }
```

Rules: (Edited, I forgot to write a small part. (auth.uid.email.replace('@','*').replace('.','*')))

```
"shared_requests": {
        "$key": {
          ".read": "root.child('shared_requests').child($key).child('user1/email').val() == auth.uid.email.replace('@','_').replace('.','_') || root.child('shared_requests').child($key).child('user2/email').val() == auth.uid.email.replace('@','_').replace('.','_')",
          ".write": "root.child('shared_requests').child($key).child('user1/email').val() == auth.uid.email.replace('@','_').replace('.','_') || root.child('shared_requests').child($key).child('user2/email').val() == auth.uid.email.replace('@','_').replace('.','_')"
        }
      }
```

But not working. How can I solve this problem?

**Edit:**

**It works when I try with the UID.**

```
"shared_req4": {
            "shared_uid": {
            "$key": {
              ".read":  "auth != null && auth.uid === $key",
                    ".write":  "auth != null && auth.uid === $key"
            }
          }
        }
```

Data:

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

Simulation results:

[image]

**But it doesn't work when I try it by email.**

```
"shared_req3": {
            "shared_uid": {
            "$key": {
              ".read":  "auth != null && auth.uid.email.replace('@','_').replace('.','_') === $key",
                    ".write":  "auth != null && auth.uid === $key"
            }
          }
      }
```

Data:

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

Simulation results:

[image]

Comment: Security rules on their own have little meaning. What code do you run against these rules? What's the result you expect from that code? And what is the result you are getting? Please edit your question to include these.

Comment: Any chance you can update the screenshots to be in English? You can temporarily override the language of the console, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970866/how-to-change-language-default-in-firebase-console-web

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I found a method that works with the UID. But I can't run this method by email.

Comment: What is `auth.uid.email` supposed to be? Did you mean `auth.token.email`? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#authtoken

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried 'auth.token.email' but it's the same error. It also works when I try 'asd_asd_com' instead of 'auth.token.email'. Could there be a problem with 'replace'? Can we see what is returned from the function?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

It doesn't work on the simulator so try on the code. And it needs to be 'auth.token.email' instead of 'auth.uid.email'.

@FrankvanPuffelen Thank you so much.

Comment: It should also work fine on the simulator *if* you provide a value for `token.email`.